# Filemaker Value Lists - Dwindling and Conditional

Tags: list, filemaker

I am trying to use a value list to show multiple repeating data, but would like the list to not only show in repeating fields, but dwindle or reduce as user makes more selections (almost like a hierarchical tree).

Is this recursion within my relationship or just conditionals with the repeating fields showing data based on whatever the calc may be.

A bit lost, but I would like to know:

1. Where to start defining the value list(s)
2. How to connect repeating fields to value list
3. How to reduce that list based on prev selection

Thanks

Comment: Have you made any attempt to find this out? There are numerous articles explaining this. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

It would be worthwhile to start with this article on conditional value lists: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5833/~/creating-conditional-value-lists

Once you understand that, you should be able to apply similar reasoning to create the best interface for your solution (which could be value lists, or drill-down portals, or some other method)

---

As an aside, using repeating fields will generally make it harder for you to get data in and out of your database and to perform calculations on the data. You might wish to use individual fields and related tables in place of repeating fields when possible.